# Не сжимается контент при изменении масштаба

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Не сжимается контент при изменении масштаба

Может ли это быть из за неправильного обнуления стилей?

на этом скриншоте видно , как я изменяю масштаб , но контент не смещается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете посмотреть сами: http://h99013sb.beget.tech/

Comment: В вашей вёрстке почти везде есть .container, попробуйте прочитать про [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap), а также для отдельных элементов  [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) и [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)

Comment: на скриншоте видно, что вы не масштаб меняете, а размер вьюпорта. При изменении именно масштаба все элементы сайта "сжимаются"

Answer (score 0):

у вас указаны четкие размеры блоков, по крайней мере в хедере один я нашел 1220px. установите размеры блокам в %.добавьте к body высоту и ширину 100%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: совет, а не конкретное решение, как в вашем случае, вполне достаточно оставлять в виде комментария, а не в виде полноценного ответа

Comment: @ZxNuClear я видимо больше разобрался в вопросе чем вы. И это не коментарий, а ответ на данную проблему. Прежде чем минусики ставить наверное стоит разобраться. Я четко указал на проблему, а именно не маштабируемая ширина блоков...

Comment: видимо вы не до конца разобрались. Откройте страницу, откройте панель разработчика, добавьте в стилях к `body` высоту и ширину в 100%, как вы советуете и для блока `container` (а не `хедер`, как вы пишите, ведь именно там указан размер в 1220px) установите 100% ширину, опять же, как вы советуете и посмотрите, даст ли это нужного результата? Вы удивитесь. К тому же, на скриншоте автор не "меняет масштаб", он открыл Эмуляцию устройства и там меняет размер вьюпорта и из-за отсутствия адаптивности он получает то, что получает

Comment: @ZxNuClear именно так я и сделал, прежде чем писать свой ответ. И как я написал не у хедера ширина, а у блока, который в хедере...

Comment: ну вы лукавите, вы уверены, что при смене ширины в 1220px на 100% и включении Эмуляции ну скажем iPad Air у вас сайт подогнался под экран, не обрезая контент?

Comment: Я картинку добавил в ответ, видно как на 1000px все сжалось. Хотя я исправил ширину у нескольких блоков body, header...

Comment: Ну а что ж вы хотя бы до 850-900px не уменьшили ширину, чтобы сделать скриншот?

Comment: @ZxNuClear потому что как я и говорил, там дальше блоки с четкими значениями идут и они не будут масштабироваться

Comment: Давайте не будем спорить, просто на других моих сайтах у меня фиксированная ширина, и там все нормально масштабируется, а именно на этом сайте эти проблемы